# Concerning meat of hard digesture

Tags: history

Relating to the history of food and cooking, I have two questions pertaining to this quote by the (rather) late [Philip Stubbs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philip_Stubbs):

[image]

Questions:

- What would constitute “meat of *hard* digesture” in 1583?
- Would there be any way to prepare such meat to make it palatable to 21st century genteel, possibly even considering the employment of honie?

Comment: I don't think it is suggesting that meat of hard digesture is unpalatable, *per se*, but that it doesn't agree with a stomach already made queasy and unsettled by eating too much honey.